# Is there a way to add entries to a dictionary in a list in json?

Tags: python, json, discord, discord.py

Is there a way to add entries to a dictionary in a list in json? (P.S. I'm not even sure if that's how I'm supposed to phrase the question)

```
base_server_datas = {
    'users': {},
}

    @commands.command()
    @commands.has_any_role(*MODERATORS, *ADMINISTRATORS)
    async def create(self, ctx, *args: str):
        faction = load_faction()
        message = " ".join(args).lower()
        new_faction = message
        if new_faction not in faction:
            faction[new_faction] = base_server_datas.copy()

            save_faction(faction)
            await ctx.send(f'**{new_faction}** cult created!')
        else:
            await ctx.send(f"{new_faction} cult already exists")

    @commands.command(case_insensitive=True)
    async def join(self, ctx, *args: str):
        faction = load_faction()
        new_user = str(ctx.author.id)
        message = " ".join(args).lower()
        existing_faction = message
        if existing_faction in faction:
            if new_user not in faction[existing_faction]["users"]:
                faction[existing_faction]["users"][new_user] = ctx.author.name
                save_faction(faction)
                await ctx.send(f"{ctx.author.mention} joined the **{message}** cult")
            else:
                await ctx.send(f"{ctx.author.mention} is already in the cult")
        else:
            await ctx.send("faction doesn\'t exist")
```

so using this code I can create a faction and can join it as well, it looks something like this:

```
{
    "h": {
        "users": {
            "535485026905882626": "Benji",
            "702646374155419648": "rosesaredumb",
            "578938036960624660": "invalid-user",
            "360366991149891585": "Goodra999"
        }
    }
}
```

but I made another title "leaders" and tried adding entries under it, but it doesn't work

It looks something like this

```
{
 "h": [
        {
            "users": {}
        },
        {
            "leaders": {}
        }
    ]
}
```

the code for this part is

```
base_server_datas2 = {
    'leaders': {},
}

@commands.command()
    async def leader(self,ctx, member: discord.Member, *args: str):
        faction = load_faction()
        new_user = str(member.id)
        message = " ".join(args).lower()
        existing_faction = message
        if existing_faction in faction:
            if new_user not in faction[existing_faction]["leaders"]:
                faction[existing_faction]["leaders"][new_user] = member.name
                save_faction(faction)
                await ctx.send(f"{ctx.author.mention} joined the **{message}** cult")
            else:
                await ctx.send(f"{ctx.author.mention} is already in the cult")
        else:
            await ctx.send("faction doesn\'t exist")
```

On adding the "leaders" title, now I can't even update the "users" dictionary

Is there any way I can add entries to both the dictionaries?

edit: this is the output I want

```
{
 "h": [
        {
            "users": {
             "702646374155419648": "rosesaredumb",
             "578938036960624660": "invalid-user"
            }
        },
        {
            "leaders": {
                        "57893803696076560": "josh"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by 'under it'. 
Please show your desired output in the question, for clarification

Comment: so you mean how to update a dictionary, where this dictionary is in a list ??

Comment: @Boomerang20thCentury yep

Comment: @ShivamJha I have added the output in edits

Answer (score 0):

first convert the dictionary `d["h"]` to a list including the current value and add the required leader's dictionary to the list:

```
di = {
    "h": {
        "users": {
            "535485026905882626": "Benji",
            "702646374155419648": "rosesaredumb",
            "578938036960624660": "invalid-user",
            "360366991149891585": "Goodra999"
        }
    }
}

to_add = {
    "leaders": {
        "57893803696076560": "josh"
    }
}

di["h"] = [di["h"], to_add]

print(di)

# Output:
# {
#     'h': [
#         {
#             'users': {
#                 '535485026905882626': 'Benji',
#                 '702646374155419648': 'rosesaredumb',
#                 '578938036960624660': 'invalid-user',
#                 '360366991149891585': 'Goodra999'
#             }
#         },
#         {
#             'leaders': {
#                 '57893803696076560': 'josh'
#             }
#         }
#     ]
# }
```

Comment: what if I want to add another entry to the "leaders" dictionary?

Comment: Then after `to_add` in `di["h"] = [di["h"], to_add]`, specify those variables in list, or use a for loop

Comment: @rad are you satisfied with this answer?

Comment: to add another to leaders,  i tired this:for item in di["h"][1]:
    di["h"][1][item]['11232310'] = 'rad'